# Taking the log difference when NAs are included in R

Tags: r

I would like to take the absolute log difference of columns of X and Y while ignoring the NAs

```
>data
       X           Y
40.29958    43.97335
52.89373    51.79441
      NA          NA
      NA          NA
27.10122          NA
39.14277    35.10647
32.26840    33.05149
27.38999    28.07941
```

My code:

```
diff <-abs(log(data$X)-log(data$Y))
```

> Error: 
>   ‘log’ not meaningful for factors

Is there a workaround in R to ignore the NAs when I make this calculation?

Comment: This error indicates that your X and Y columns do not have numeric values. Could you share str(data) here.

Comment: The log of a number < 0 is negative which will give a misleading result.

Answer (score 0):

The `NA`s are no problem for the functions used. If you calculate the log, difference and absolute values with just `NA`s it will return `NA`. As @rar suggested, your problem lies in the structure of your columns. It seems like `data$X` and `data$Y` are of class `factor` which can not be evaluated by the `log` function (see your error message). You could just convert them to numeric before passing them onto the log function, so:

```
 diff <-abs(log(as.numeric(data$X))-log(as.numeric(data$Y)))
```

Please doublecheck the structure of your dataframe to confirm that you `X` and `Y` are indeed of class `factor`: `str(data)`